# VSCode Python autocomplete for generated code in separate directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, pants

I use pants to manage a Python project that uses protocol buffers.  Pants places the generated `_pb2.py` and `_pb2.pyi` files under a separate `dist/codegen` tree.  Is it possible to get VS Code autocomplete to work when using the `_pb2` modules?

The file tree looks like this:

```
.
|-- dist/
|   `-- codegen/
|       `-- src/
|           `-- project/
|               |-- data_pb2.py
|               `-- data_pb2.pyi
`-- src/
    `-- project/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- code.py
        `-- data.proto
```

And in `code.py` I have import statements like this:

```
from project import data_pb2
```

I've tried setting `python.analysis.extraPaths` to `["dist/codegen/src"]` in `settings.json`.  This makes pylance stop complaining that `data_pb2` is missing.  But autocomplete still does not work, and pylance has no type information for members of `data_pb2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python implicit namespace packages ([PEP 420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/)) to make this work.  Namespace packages are allowed to have modules within the same package reside in different directories.  Which allows pylance and other tools to work correctly when code is split between `src` and `dist/codegen/src`.

To use implicit namespace packages, you just need to remove `src/package/__init__.py`, and leave `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` set to `["dist/codegen/src"]`.

See also the GitHub issue [microsoft/pylance-release#2855](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2855), which describes using implicit namespace packages to make pylance work correctly in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `python.analysis.extraPaths` with the following extent:

```
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "./dist/codegen/src"
     ],
```

And adding the following code to your code.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".\dist\codegen\src")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help.  Still no autocomplete or typing information.  Note that there's no `__init__.py` in `dist/codegen/src/project` so I wouldn't expect modifying `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` to help here.

Comment: This works for me. And it doesn't need to creat __init__.py in it. And how can pylance recognize the __pb2 if you don't tell it by modifying sys.path or PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I do get autocomplete and typing information if I put my proto in a separate directory.  E.g., `src/project/code.py` and `src/data/data.proto` which generates `dist/codegen/src/data/data_pb2.py`.  It seems like having the generated code at the same path causes issues.